# Getting the error message: “Could not find a part of the path"

Tags: c#, pdf, path

I create a Folder (File) and i want that after i click the button (btnGenerate_Click) it should create a pdf file and save it into the Folder, named "File". But i constantly getting the error message: "Could not find a part of the path "C:\User\VS\Intra\Intra.Admin\File\" But the Location of the path is correct....

```html
protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string FilePath = MapPath("~/File/"); //here!
             

            iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create));
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "Message";
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Font.Bold = true;
            GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();

            Response.Write(pdfDoc);

            Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
            Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
            Response.End();

        }
```

Comment: Where is the name of the file? This is a folder name that you are trying to use like it were a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FilePath is a directory. You should append a filename, so something like this:

```
string FilePath = MapPath("~/File/" + fileName);
```

Comment: I don not how to create in this Situation a fileName..... string FilePath = MapPath("~/File/doc.pdf");

Comment: * I don not know how to create in this Situation a FileName, but I have followed your advice and changed it to string FilePath = MapPath("~File/doc.pdf);